# Python UDP client did not respond

Tags: python, python-2.7, udpclient

A python UDP client:

```
root@kali-linux:~# python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 17 2017, 18:50:44) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> target_host = "127.0.0.1"
>>> target_port = 80
>>> client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> client.sendto("AAABBBCCC",(target_host,target_port))
9
>>> data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)
        # to this line,no response
>>>print data   # waiting for imput
```

when I input "data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)" then ENTER,I wait for ten minutes that no response.

But when I program a TCP client,it work.This is code:

```
root@kali-linux:~# python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 17 2017, 18:55:37) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import socket
>>>target_host = "www.baidu.com"
>>>target_port = 80
>>>client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>>client.connect((target_host,target_port))
>>>client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: baidu.com\r\n\r\n")
35
>>>response = client.recv(4096)
>>>print response 
#output
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 12:05:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 14613
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Nov 2017 03:00:00 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

AND SO ON ..........
```

TCP client can work and UDP client can't work,why?

what should I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to send and receive through the same socket? Also, please stop using Python 2.

Comment: @zmbq the same socket ? I think the code no error,and when I program TCP client with same sample it can do work.

Comment: IMHO, you have to start two processes: listening on this port (server) and sending data to port (client) to successfully transfer data. Possibly you have some software (80 port points to a http server like nginx or apache httpd) listening to a 80/TCP port. Check this like this: 1) $ telnet 127.0.0.1 80 (should succeed connecting - you'll see a black screen possibly with httpd server prompt), 2) $ netstat -tulpan | grep 80

Comment: @lospejos I don't any software, I just work on interactive console, but when I program TCP client with python,it work,I can send data and receice data,please see my problem.

Comment: @lospejos TCP client can work and UDP client can't work,why?

Comment: In provided example you are connecting to a server www.baidu.com which has server software litening on port 80. If you try to connect in you TCP example to host 127.0.0.1 on port 80, you'll get connection error

Comment: @lospejos Yes ,you are right, I know .In TCP client ,www.baidu.com is server, so connecting to www.baidu.com can receive data.But 127.0.0.1 is localhost that is not server,so connect to 127.0.0.1 can't receive data.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP ports and TCP ports are different entities. You can have a TCP server running on TCP port 80 and something entirely different on UDP port 80 (e.g. an NTP server, although this is normally running on UDP port 123).

In your first code snippet you are sending a UDP packet to the UDP port 80. Mostly likely nothing is listening on UDP port 80 so the packet is silently discarded.

You line `data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)` is then waiting for *someone* (not necessarily the server you sent the request to) sending you another UDP packet. Since usually there is nothing listening on UDP port 80 nothign happens, and the `revcfrom` call waits forever. It works ok. This is expected.

What you could do to receive something:
1. bind() your socket of your UDP snippet to port 2222 (or any free port), and run it. It will again wait forever.
2. Run a second instance (in a different shell) with `target_port = 2222'. Now you should receive a UDP packet with the content "AAABBBCCC" on the first instance.

In your second code snippet you are using TCP and you are contacting a web server on TCP port 80 (not UDP port 80) which responds. This works as expected as you can see, but only since there is something running on TCP port 80.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer,I know.

Comment: Thanks! It would be brilliant if you could then accept this answer. :-)